# Chrome Extension Privilege Escalation Possible?

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, browser-security

Suppose I install an extension E that requested privileges A (e.g., tabs). Suppose this extension is malicious. Further suppose that the extension system has a binding-layer bug that E can leverage to execute arbitrary code in the extension process. Can E use other privileged APIs besides those permitted by A?

That is are the actual privileged APIs isolated in a separate process from the extension core process?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual privileged APIs"? Are you meaning APIs beyond those that are published for Chrome extensions, or just ones which the extension would normally need to specify a `permissions` entry?

Comment: The first question here is a poor question. You are effectively asking: If 1===1, does 1===1?

Comment: *other privileged APIs*: For example, can the extension use the history API even though it wasn't listed in the permission list.

Comment: You can postpone the permission warning and capability with optional permissions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lei Zhang for clarifying this on the chromium irc channel ([see here](https://echelog.com/logs/browse/chromium/1490396400)): the actual permissions are checked on the browser-side where the APIs are implemented, not the extension (renderer) process.